# MSMQ Listener (windows service) can't receive messages independently after installation

Tags: msmq

I have two services running asynchronously.  service1 is posting messages to MessageQueue which is in service2 (response queue).
Service2 is picking up each and every message from the queue and processing it.
problem is when ever service1 stops running because it finished sending messages.... service2 is not able to read the messages(still service2 is running) from the queue(still queue has some messages to read).

It is like service 2 becomes dormant when service one ended and the app is closed.  Is this behavior expected?? Is there a solution.

I would like to have my service2(msmq listener) to continue to receive messages independently from Service 1.

```
 using System; 
using System.Diagnostics; 
using System.Net.NetworkInformation; 
using System.ServiceModel; 
using System.ServiceProcess; 
using System.Threading; 
using LOGGER; 
using MSMQ.INTERFACE; 
using RightFax; 
using Tools.Helper; 
using Microsoft.VisualBasic; 
using RFCOMAPILib; 
using FAXHandlerClass = FAXHandlerClass; 
using FAXHandlerState = CONTENT.SYSTEM.FAXHandlerState; 

namespace MSMQ.LISTENER 
{ 
    public partial class Service1 : ServiceBase 
    { 
        public static FaxServer RFFaxApi; 
        private const string LogClass = "MSMQ.LISTENER.PROGRAM::"; 
        private static bool _mBoolMustStop; 
        private static readonly RF2MQCounter Counter = new RF2MQCounter(); 
        private static RFaxServerStatus _rightFaxServerStatus; 
        public static FAXHandlerState MThState = new FAXHandlerState(); 
        private IMessageQueueHandler _queue; 
        public Service1() 
        { 
            InitializeComponent(); 
        } 

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args) 
        { 
            try 
            { 
                var logRoust = "OnStart"; 
                Generic.ConfigParam = LoadConfig.Invoke(LogClass); 

                //Ping the server 
                PingReply rep; 
                var mac = PingServer.Mac(out rep, Generic.ConfigParam.RightFax.server); 
                if (rep != null) 
                { 
                    Logger.Log(string.Format(@"Pinging {0} [{1}]", mac, rep.Address)); 
                    Logger.Log(string.Format("Reply From {0} : time={1} TTL={2}", rep.Address, rep.RoundtripTime, 
                                             rep.Options.Ttl)); 
                    //Connect to the Right Fax Server 
                    Actions.Connect(LogClass, Counter, ref RFFaxApi); 

                    //Start readin gthe queue 
                    IMessageQueueHandler _queue = new Test(); 
                    var threadQueuet = new Thread(_queue.StartRead); 
                    Logger.Log(string.Format("Start reading {0} queue...", 
                                             Generic.ConfigParam.MSMQ.responseQueue)); 
                    threadQueuet.Start(); 
                } 
                else 
                { 
                    Logger.Log(string.Format("Not able to  get a reply From {0} : time={1} TTL={2}", rep.Address, 
                                             rep.RoundtripTime, rep.Options.Ttl)); 
                } 
            } 
            catch (PingException e) 
            { 
                throw; 
            } 
            catch (Exception e) 
            { 
                Logger.Log(string.Format("{0} ::Not able to  start the  MSMQ.LISTENER Service on : {1}  Mesage:: {2}", LogClass, Generic.ConfigParam.RightFax.server, e.Message )); 
                throw; 
            } 
        } 


        protected override void OnStop() 
        { 
            if (_queue != null) 
                _queue.StopRead(); 
            Logger.Log(string.Format("Stopping MSMQ.LISTENER Service {0} queue...", Generic.ConfigParam.MSMQ.responseQueue)); 
        } 

        /// <summary> 
        /// Connect to the Rightfax server 
        /// </summary> 
        /// <param name="ref">Used for logging the routine</param> 
        /// <returns>The RightFax server connection status</returns> 
        /// <remarks></remarks> 
        public static RFaxServerStatus ConnectToRightFax(string @ref) 
        { 
            var logRoust = @ref + LogClass + "CONNECTION::"; 

            var retryCounter = 0; 

            Generic.ConfigParam = LoadConfig.Invoke(LogClass,Counter); 
            Logger.Log(string.Format("{0} - Connecting to {1} as user {2}", logRoust, Generic.ConfigParam.RightFax.server, "")); 
            _rightFaxServerStatus = RFaxServerStatus.Connecting; 

            try 
            { 
                if ((RFFaxApi != null)) 
                    RFFaxApi.CloseServer(); 
            } 
            catch 
            { 
                //We do nothing.... We will destroy the object anyway 
                //return false; 
            } 
            RFFaxApi = null; 

            do 
            { 
                MThState.AddEventState = new FAXHandlerClass(FaxHandlerStateEnum.ConnectingRfax); 

                try 
                { 
                    //********************************************************************************************** 
                    //    This section determines how quickly we try to reconnect 
                    //    Try the 1st 5 times 5 second apart 
                    //        the 2nd 5 times 30 seconds apart 
                    //        the 3rd 5 times 60 seconds apart 
                    //        every 300 seconds (5 mins) forever after that 
                    //********************************************************************************************** 
                    int sleepInterval; 
                    if (retryCounter > 15) 
                    { 
                        sleepInterval = 300000; 
                    } 
                    else 
                    { 
                        if (retryCounter > 10) 
                        { 
                            sleepInterval = 60000; 
                        } 
                        else 
                        { 
                            sleepInterval = retryCounter > 5 ? 30000 : 5000; 
                        } 
                    } 


                    //************************************************** 
                    //    Connect to the RightFax Server 
                    //************************************************** 
                    Logger.Log(string.Format("{0} - Attempt # {1}", logRoust, retryCounter)); 

                    if (retryCounter > 0) 
                    { 
                        Logger.Log(string.Format("{0} - Waiting # {1} seconds before trying to reconnect.", logRoust, sleepInterval / 1000)); 
                        Thread.Sleep(sleepInterval); 
                    } 



                    Logger.Log(string.Format("{0} - Initializing Connection to RightFax.", logRoust)); 

                    RFFaxApi = new FaxServer 
                    { 
                        ServerName = Generic.ConfigParam.RightFax.server.Trim(), 
                        UseNTAuthentication = RFCOMAPILib.BoolType.False, 
                        AuthorizationUserID = Generic.ConfigParam.RightFax.userID, 
                        AuthorizationUserPassword = Generic.ConfigParam.RightFax.password, 
                        Protocol = (CommunicationProtocolType)Generic.ConfigParam.RightFax.communicationProtocol 
                    }; 
                    //Verify if the RightFax Service is runing before connecting 
                    //var controller = new ServiceController("RightFax Server Module", _rfFaxApi.ServerName); 
                    //if ((controller.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.Running))) 
                    //{ 
                    try 
                    { 
                        RFFaxApi.OpenServer(); 
                        _rightFaxServerStatus = RFaxServerStatus.Connected; 
                        retryCounter = 0; 
                        Logger.Log(string.Format("{0} - Connected to {1} (V. {2}) as user {3}", logRoust, RFFaxApi.ServerName, RFFaxApi.Version, RFFaxApi.AuthorizationUserID)); 

                    } 
                    catch (Exception ex) 
                    { 

                        Logger.Log(string.Format("{0} - ERROR Connected to {1} (V. {2}) as user {3} MESSAGE: {4}", logRoust, RFFaxApi.ServerName, RFFaxApi.Version, RFFaxApi.AuthorizationUserID, ex.Message)); 
                    } 


                } 
                catch (System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException ex) 
                { 
                    //Its OK not to end the loop. This is possibly a temporary error condition. 
                    Logger.Log(string.Format("{0} - Connection failed Message: {1}", logRoust, ex.Message), EventLogEntryType.Warning); 
                } 
                catch (Exception ex) 
                { 
                    if (Strings.InStr(ex.Source, "RFComAPI.FaxServer") > 0 | Strings.InStr(ex.Source, "Interop.RFCOMAPILib") > 0) 
                    { 
                        //Its OK not to end the loop. This is possibly a temporary error condition. 
                        Logger.Log(string.Format("{0} - Connection failed : Message {1} ", logRoust, ex.Message), EventLogEntryType.Warning); 
                    } 
                    else 
                    { 
                        _rightFaxServerStatus = RFaxServerStatus.NotConnected; 
                        Logger.Log(string.Format("{0} - Connection failed. Message: {1}", logRoust, ex.Message), EventLogEntryType.Error); 
                        throw new Exception(string.Format("{0} - Connection failed. Message: {1}", logRoust, ex.Message)); 
                    } 

                } 
                finally 
                { 
                    retryCounter += 1; 
                } 

            } while (!(_rightFaxServerStatus == RFaxServerStatus.Connected | _mBoolMustStop)); 
            return _rightFaxServerStatus; 

        } 
    } 
} 


--------------------------------------------- 
using System.Net.NetworkInformation; 
using System.ServiceProcess; 
using System.Threading; 
using LOGGER; 
using MSMQ.INTERFACE; 
using .RightFax; 
using Tools.Helper; 
using RFCOMAPILib; 
using FAXHandlerState = HandlerState; 

namespace MSMQ.LISTENER 
{ 
    static class Program 
    { 


        private const string LogClass = "MSMQ.LISTENER.PROGRAM::"; 
        public static FaxServer RFFaxApi; 

        private static bool _mBoolMustStop; 
        private static readonly RF2MQCounter Counter = new RF2MQCounter(); 
        private static RFaxServerStatus _rightFaxServerStatus; 
        public static FAXHandlerState MThState = new FAXHandlerState(); 

        /// <summary> 
        /// The main entry point for the application. 
        /// </summary> 
        static void Main() 
        { 
             Run(); 
            //OR comment above to be able to Debug 
            //Uncomment below to start in debug mode 
         // Start(); 
        } 

        private static void Run() 
        { 
            var servicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
                                              { 
                                                  new Service1() 
                                              }; 
            ServiceBase.Run(servicesToRun); 
        } 
        public static void StartThreadProc(object stateInfo) 
        { 
            Start(); 
        } 


        public static void Start() 
        { 
            try 
            { 
                var logRoust = "OnStart"; 
                Generic.ConfigParam = LoadConfig.Invoke(LogClass); 

                //Ping the server 
                PingReply rep; 
                var mac = PingServer.Mac(out rep, Generic.ConfigParam.RightFax.server); 
                if (rep != null) 
                { 
                    Logger.Log(string.Format(@"Pinging {0} [{1}]", mac, rep.Address)); 
                    Logger.Log(string.Format("Reply From {0} : time={1} TTL={2}", rep.Address, rep.RoundtripTime, 
                                             rep.Options.Ttl)); 
                    //Connect to the Right Fax Server 
                    Actions.Connect(LogClass, Counter, ref RFFaxApi); 

                    //Start readin gthe queue 
                    IMessageQueueHandler _queue = new Isoconvoceresponse(); 
                    var threadQueuet = new Thread(_queue.StartRead); 
                    Logger.Log(string.Format("Start reading {0} queue...", 
                                             Generic.ConfigParam.MSMQ.responseQueue)); 
                    threadQueuet.Start(); 
                } 
                else 
                { 
                    Logger.Log(string.Format("Not able to  get a reply From {0} : time={1} TTL={2}", rep.Address, 
                                             rep.RoundtripTime, rep.Options.Ttl)); 
                } 
            } 
            catch (PingException e) 
            { 
                throw; 
            } 
        } 


    } 
} 


___________________________ 
namespace MSMQ.INTERFACE 
{ 
    public interface IMessageQueueHandler 
    { 
        void StartRead(); 
        void StopRead(); 
    } 
} 
-------------- 
using System; 
using System.Diagnostics; 
using System.Globalization; 
using System.Messaging; 
using System.Net.NetworkInformation; 
using System.ServiceModel; 
using System.ServiceProcess; 
using System.Threading; 
using CONTENT.SYSTEM; 
using LOGGER; 
using MSMQ.INTERFACE; 
using RightFax; 
using RightFax.Tools.Helper; 
using RFCOMAPILib; 
using MessageQueue = System.Messaging.MessageQueue; 
using RF2MQCounter = RF2MQCounter; 

namespace MSMQ.LISTENER 
{ 

    public class Test : IMessageQueueHandler 
    { 
        private MessageQueue _queue; 
        private readonly string _queueName; 
        private const string LogClass = ".MSMQ.LISTENER::"; 
        private readonly ManualResetEvent manualResetEvent = new ManualResetEvent(true); 
        private long handle ; 

        /// <summary> 
        /// 
        /// </summary> 
        public Test() 
        { 

            const string logroust = LogClass + "Isoconvoceresponse"; 
            Generic.ConfigParam = LoadConfig.Invoke(logroust); 
            _queueName =Generic.ConfigParam.MSMQ.responseQueue; 
        } 

        /// <summary> 
        /// 
        /// </summary> 
        public void StartRead() 
        { 

           // System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break(); 
            const string logRoust = LogClass + "StartRead::"; 
            try 
            { 
                Logger.Log(String.Format("{0} - Start Reading the {1} Queue .", logRoust, Generic.ConfigParam.MSMQ.responseQueue )); 
                _queue = new MessageQueue(_queueName) {Formatter = new XmlMessageFormatter(new[] {typeof (string)})}; 

                _queue.MessageReadPropertyFilter.SetAll(); 
                var objDefProps = new System.Messaging.DefaultPropertiesToSend 
                { 
                    Priority = MessagePriority.High, 
                    Recoverable = true, 
                    UseDeadLetterQueue = true, 
                    UseJournalQueue = true, 

                }; 
                _queue.DefaultPropertiesToSend = objDefProps; 



                _queue.PeekCompleted += QueuePeekCompleted; 
                _queue.BeginPeek(); 
                //_queue.ReceiveCompleted += QueueReceiveCompletedd;//Event handler 
                //_queue.BeginReceive(); 



            } 
            catch (Exception ex) 
            { 
                Actions.SetGenericFlagOff(handle.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),Generic.ConfigParam.dbConnectionString); 
                Logger.Log( 
                    String.Format("{0} - Start Reading the {1} failed  : Error: {2}.", logRoust, Generic.ConfigParam.MSMQ.responseQueue, ex.Message), 
                    EventLogEntryType.Error); 
                throw; 
            } 
        } 

        public static void OnServiceFaulted(object sender, EventArgs e) 
        { 

            Logger.Log(string.Format("{0} ::Service Faulted: {1}  Mesage:: {2}", LogClass, Generic.ConfigParam.RightFax.server, e.ToString())); 

        } 


        public void StopRead() 
        {//make the process synchronous before closing the queue 
            manualResetEvent.WaitOne(); 

            if (_queue == null) return; 
            _queue.Close(); 
            _queue = null; 
        } 

        /// <summary> 
        /// 
        /// </summary> 
        /// <param name="sender"></param> 
        /// <param name="e"></param> 
        private void QueuePeekCompleted(object sender, PeekCompletedEventArgs e) 
        { 


           // System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break(); 
            const string logRoust = LogClass + "QueuePeekCompleted::"; 

            var message = _queue.EndPeek(e.AsyncResult); 
            _queue.Receive(); 
            _queue.BeginPeek(); 

          var allMessagesOnResponseQueue = _queue.GetAllMessages(); 

          foreach (var msg in allMessagesOnResponseQueue) 
          { 
              Logger.Log(String.Format("{0} - Messages QueuePeekCompleted event handler {1}", logRoust, message.Label + " - " + message.Id)); 


          } 
          do 
            { 

                try 
                { 
                    if (message.MessageType == MessageType.Acknowledgment) 
                        switch (message.Acknowledgment) 
                        { 
                            case Acknowledgment.Purged: 
                                Logger.Log("Message Purged {0}", message.Body.ToString()); 
                                break; 
                            case Acknowledgment.QueueExceedMaximumSize: 
                                Logger.Log("Message Queue Exceed MaximumSize {0}", message.Body.ToString()); 
                                break; 
                            case Acknowledgment.QueuePurged: 
                                Logger.Log("Message Queue Purged {0}", message.Body.ToString()); 
                                break; 
                            case Acknowledgment.ReceiveTimeout: 
                                Logger.Log("Message ReceiveTimeout {0}, Now restarting MSMQ.LISTENER Service", 
                                           message.Body.ToString()); 
                                var controller = new ServiceController("MSMQ.LISTENER", "STHA38994.iad.ca.inet"); 
                                if (controller.Status.Equals(ServiceControllerStatus.Running)) 
                                    controller.Start(); 
                                break; 
                            case Acknowledgment.ReachQueue: 
                                Logger.Log("Message Reached Queue {0}", message.Body.ToString()); 
                                break; 
                            case Acknowledgment.Receive: 
                                Logger.Log("Message Received {0}", message.Body.ToString()); 
                                break; 
                        } 

                    /
                    if (message.MessageType == MessageType.Normal) 
                    { 
                        var messageDetail = message.Label.Split(' '); 
                        var pdfFileDetails = messageDetail[1].Split('_'); 
                         handle = Convert.ToInt64(pdfFileDetails[0]); 
                        var isSucessfull = false; 

                        FaxServer faxServer = null; 
                        if (MSMQ.LISTENER.Service1.RFFaxApi == null) 
                        { 
                            Generic.ConfigParam = LoadConfig.Invoke(LogClass); 
                            var counter = new RF2MQCounter(); 

                            Actions.Connect(LogClass, counter, ref faxServer); //you can pass a null faxserver 

                        } 

                        if (faxServer != null) 
                        { 


                            try 
                            { 
                                Logger.Log("Getting Fax {0}", handle.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)); 
                                var rfaxFax = Actions.GetFax(handle, ref faxServer); 
                                Logger.Log("Getting Fax {0} SUCESS", handle.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)); 
                                Generic.NumberOfRecordsSent++; 
                                Logger.Log("Processing message {0}", handle.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)); 
                                isSucessfull = RFServiceClass.ProcessMessage(message, ref rfaxFax); 
                                Logger.Log("Processing message SUCESS {0}", 
                                           handle.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)); 

                            } 
                            catch (Exception ex) 
                            { 
                                Generic.NumberOfRecordsSent--; 
                                Logger.Log( 
                                    String.Format("{0} - ERROR processinf fax from the queue.. {1}", logRoust, 
                                                  ex.Message), EventLogEntryType.Error); 
                                Actions.SetGenericFlagOff(handle.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), 
                                                          Generic.ConfigParam.dbConnectionString); 
                            } 
                        } 
                    } 
                } 
                catch (MessageQueueException msq) 
                { 
                    var messageDetail = message.Label.Split(' '); 
                    var pdfFileDetails = messageDetail[1].Split('_'); 
                    long handle = Convert.ToInt64(pdfFileDetails[0]); 
                    Actions.SetGenericFlagOff(handle.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), Generic.ConfigParam.dbConnectionString); 
                    switch (msq.MessageQueueErrorCode) 
                    { 
                        case MessageQueueErrorCode.IOTimeout: 
                            Logger.Log( 
                                String.Format("{0} - Error Message IOTimeout Exception: {1}.", logRoust, msq.Message), 
                                EventLogEntryType.Error); 
                            Actions.SetGenericFlagOff(handle.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),Generic.ConfigParam.dbConnectionString ); 
                            break;                     
                         default: 
                            Logger.Log( 
                                String.Format("{0} - Error Message DEFAULT Exception: {1}.", logRoust, msq.Message), 
                                EventLogEntryType.Error); 
                            break; 
                    } 

                } 
                catch (Exception ex) 
                { 
                    Actions.SetGenericFlagOff(handle.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), Generic.ConfigParam.dbConnectionString); 
                    Logger.Log( 
                        String.Format("{0} - Error QueuePeekCompleted: {1}.", logRoust, ex.Message), 
                        EventLogEntryType.Error); 
                    message = null; 
                } 
            } while (message != null); 

        } 
        } 

        public override string ToString() 
        { 
            return _queueName; 
        } 
    } 
}
```

Comment: That won't be an MSMQ issue. The usage of a queue (or not) by one process shouldn't impact the state of another process in this way.

Comment: So.. Maybe I should check if there are messages in the queue that have not been picked up by ReceiveComplete Event Handler (stuck messages??)before sending new messages by using the Use GetMessageEnumerator2() . Then If there are messages still in the queue, process it as usual then send new message to queue.

Comment: You should be able to run both services at the same time and not require such a workaround. I'm not a coder so haven't gone through your services but it sounds like there is a shared component which becomes unavailable when the sender stops sending.